# How to use graph api for social login in Azure AD B2C without using Microsoft page?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am creating an application that uses Azure AD B2C for authorization where I'm not going to use Microsoft's login page. Here in this customized login page, I want to use social login.

I have already done login for Azure AD B2C registered user using Graph Api(RPOC User flow). I need to do the same for the social network user login.

POST https://MyApplication.b2clogin.com/MyApplication.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_test_rpoc

```
BODY

username:******
password:******
grant_type:password
scope: ********
client_id: *******
response_type:token id_token

RESPONSE

{
   "access_token":,
   "token_type":,
   "expires_in":,
   "refresh_token":,
   "id_token":
}
```

Is there any such kind of graph API or any way we can get token from Azure AD B2C for social network user login.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to implement it in a custom policy if the social IdP supports ROPC as well.
There's a good chance they won't though.

B2C allows UI customization, so if you want a custom login page, it'd be better to use that instead of ROPC.

Comment: Yes though it is possible I can't use customized page. Is there any way to authenticate social network **Access Token** in Azure AD.

Comment: An access token you got from e.g. Facebook or another social IdP? Not in a good way no.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can achieve is to place a Facebook button in your native app which launches the B2C policy with a domaim_hint parameter attached such that B2C auto redirects the user to Facebook. The entire flow still has to be in a web view. Social IdPs like Facebook don’t support ROPC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin